# How to assign string value to variable from curl and jq in shell script?

Tags: macos, shell, curl, jq

I am trying to assign a string I get from curl and jq to a variable. this is my code below, but it doesn't work. I am a Mac user.

```
value=$(curl -X GET curl -X GET https://apitest.onkore.com/onkore/api/v1/storeCategories | jq '.[2] | ._id')
```

Comment: got this working without any changes `echo $value
"59178d2a4ca53714085a0903"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ value=$(curl -X GET https://apitest.onkore.com/onkore/api/v1/storeCategories | 
  jq '.[2] | ._id')
$ echo "$value"
"59178d2a4ca53714085a0903"
```

In other words, "curl -X GET curl -X GET" is incorrect.

P.S. You might want to use the -r command-line option of jq.

Comment: It works! I just realized I accidentally typed "curl -X GET" twice.